# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Network' of undefined" in vis-network

Tags: vis.js, visnetwork

I am trying to create a vis-network in vueJS 2.6
My vis-network version is 8.3.2
I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'Network' of undefined" in vis-network
following is my code

```
  <div id="mynetwork"></div>
</template>

<script>
import vis from 'vis-network'
export default {
  data() {
          return {
            network: null,
            nodes: [
              { id: 1, shape: "circularImage"},
              { id: 2, shape: "circularImage"},
            ],
            edges: [
              { from: 1, to: 2 },
            ],
            options: {
              },
            },
            container: "",
          };
        },

        mounted() {
          this.container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
          var data = {
            nodes: this.nodes,
            edges: this.edges,
          };
          this.network = new vis.Network(this.container, data, this.options);
        },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved It by replacing the import statement
`import {Network } from 'vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min'`